# How to take off the y-overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a vertical tab system. I have several problems yet, but I am having problems with it without overflowing in y position.

I believe I am not working out well with the content part.

```
     <div class="content">
<h3 class="heading">Tab 4 Content</h3>
<p class="description">Lorem cumque.</p>
```

```js
// ----------------- Variables

wrapper = $(".tabs");
tabs = wrapper.find(".nav-tab");
tabToggle = wrapper.find(".tab-toggle");

// ----------------- Functions

function openTab() {
  var content = $(this).parent().next(".content"),
    activeItems = wrapper.find(".active");

  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).add(content).add(activeItems).toggleClass('active');
    wrapper.css('min-height', content.outerHeight());
  }
};

// ----------------- Interactions

tabToggle.on('click', openTab);

// ----------------- Constructor functions

$(window).load(function() {
  tabToggle.first().trigger('click');
});
```

```css
button,
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75rem 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #374d72;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button:hover,
.button:hover {
  background-color: #374d72;
}

button:hover:before,
button:hover:after,
.button:hover:before,
.button:hover:after {
  color: #4cc4cf;
}

button:after,
button:before,
.button:after,
.button:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------- Vertical Tabs */

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  /* ---------------------- Tab */
  /* ---------------------- Content */
}

.tabs .nav-tab {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  /* ---------------------- Tab Toggle */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  .tabs .nav-tab {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
}

.tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle {
  padding: 1rem 4rem 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  .tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle {
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle:after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  .tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
  }
}

.tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle.active {
  color: #8099c2;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
}

.tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle.active:after {
  color: #8099c2;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(50%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(50%);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(50%);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  .tabs .nav-tab .tab-toggle.active:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(0);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(0);
    right: 1rem;
  }
}

.tabs .content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  .tabs .content {
    max-height: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.tabs .content.active {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 10rem) {
  .tabs .content.active {
    max-height: none;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.tabs .content>.heading {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="nav-tab">
        <button class="tab-toggle">Tab 1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 class="heading">Tab 1 Content</h3>
        <p class="description">Lorem cumque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-tab">
        <button class="tab-toggle">Tab 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3 class="heading">Tab 2 Content</h3>
        <p class="description">Lorem cumque.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made it full width, but dont want it overflowing

Comment: The title says "y-overflow", the question body says "appear on hover" and "increase width". I'm not sure what you want help with...

Comment: @msanford my mistake, sorry. Just edited it

Comment: You need to include a [mcve] in your question, not only on jsFiddle

Comment: @j08691 I believe now it is like that. Thanks for the info there!

Comment: No, you still only have three lines of HTML here, while you have far more than that on jsFiddle including CSS and JS.

Comment: I solved the issue, had some data in CSS that was creating the issue that I was trying to solve!

Comment: @JoseAfonso If you remember what the solution was, you should post it as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted to let others know that it was resolved.